# Image doesn't appears in the browser javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, function

I'm doing a project with `HTML`, `CSS` and `` and I pretend after the `Yes` button is clicked, should appear the image `noite.png` and after that the counter must be equal to 0 (I need this counter to know how many times the person needed to answer correctly the question).

The following `HTML`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Frango - O Jogo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <input id='btn_No' type="button" value="No" onclick="click_No()">
    <input id='btn_Yes' type="button" value="Yes" onclick="click_Yes()">
    <div id="res"></div>
    <img id="img" src="" alt="">
    <script src="script.js">
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
var contador = 0
var img = document.getElementById('img')

function click_No(){
    res.innerHTML = `Que pena, tente de novo!`
    contador++
}

    function click_Yes(){
    res.innerHTML = `Acertou! Levaste ${contador}vezes para acertar!`
    img.src = ('noite.png')
    contador = 0
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the following `CSS`:

```
body{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14pt;
}
input{
    margin: 10px 10px;
    font-size: larger;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px;
}

#btn_No{
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    border-color: rgb(253, 10, 10);
}

#btn_Yes{
    background-color: rgb(42, 226, 5);
    border-color: rgb(42, 226, 5);
}
```

Here's the output: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly8q5.png)

But the image doesn't appear in the browser and the counter and the counter isn't equal to 0. I think the js isn't running the lines 12 and 13 of the script. Could someone help me?

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve] _not as images_.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have two `click_Yes` functions, of which the former is overridden by the latter. Simply change one of them to `click_No`.

Comment: It still not working mate

Answer (score 0):

InSync is correct

1. JavaScript should be in head with defer or last thing in body, other ways it will not select elements after script tag ! try console.log(img)
2. Naming conventions and modern practices, eg: camelCase, use let and const.

Comment: It still not working mate

Comment: @sharp.programer Told you to put script last thing in body .. its above the image that;s why nothing selected

Comment: I already did your suggestions and it still not working my friend. I edited again the post with your suggestion in the code.

Comment: man .. im running your code .. its working just put the <script> ... tag after img.. last thing in body .. also make sure of image file name in src